# solid mode objects have highlighted area & distortions in material mode

Tags: 3d-view, distort

I have an issue were some objects have a strange highlight area around the centre in solid view mode, in material preview the objects have a distortion on the reflection. The 2 main raised panels show a lighter area just off centre.

The left hand side object is a copy  and removed the panels then recreated and all appears fine.

But I cannot see what is wrong with the original, normals appear ok and comparing statistics it appears ok.

You can see the issue between the two raised panels on the left hand side of each object.

[image: solid view]

[image: Material preview]

thanks for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to lack of geometry. There are several solutions to this, here are my 2 favorites:
If you are using a bevel modifier use more segments, or harden normals.

If you want to use hardened normals, you need to set your object to smooth shading (as it already is in your screenhot) and then go here:
[image]

Enable auto smooth. This could solve your problem even without the bevel modifier.